# PHP multiple values insert to each row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this variable in PHP:

```
$game_rate = implode(",",$_POST['game_rate']);
$game_opt = implode(",",$_POST['game_opt']);
```

And now I want to insert it into MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO t_game(game_rate, game_opt) VALUES('$game_rate', '$game_opt')
```

The data show in table:

```
game_rate | game_opt
8,5       | 7,5
```

What I want is, is it possible insert the data in each row. So it can be like this:

```
game_rate | game_opt
8         | 7
5         | 5
```

Comment: What is the value of $_POST['game_rate'] before implode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using foreach loop.

```
$game = $_POST['game_rate']; // with the proviso $ _ POST ['game_rate'] is an array
$game_opt = $_POST['game_opt'];
$index = 0;
foreach($game as $g){
   $query = "INSERT INTO t_game(game_rate, game_opt) VALUES('$g', '".$game_opt[$index]."')";
   // Execute the query variabel
   $index++;
}
```

Comment: How about if the variable more than 3?

Comment: foreach loop will execute end of the array. So don't feel about how many values are there in it

Comment: there will be no problem. because when we use the foreach loop, it will repeat until the amount of data from $game variable. check this for detail about foreach : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Its not good practice to use `insert` query within `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it with single query. Just create the query with multiple values. Try with -

```
"INSERT INTO t_game(game_rate) VALUES(" . implode(") , (", $_POST['game_rate']) . ")"
```

> Assuming the values will be integer. If they are string then have to add quotes properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
 foreach($_POST['game_rate'] as $k=>$v){
         if($k==0){
         $temp = " values('$v','".$_POST['game_opt'][$k]."')";
        }else{
        $temp .= ", values('$v','".$_POST['game_opt'][$k]."')";
        }
        }
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_game(game_rate,game_opt) $temp";
//Execute your query here
```

Comment: How about if the variable more than 3?

Comment: In your question it is only one variable.